# Combine two arrays separating by comma

Tags: php, arrays

I have these two arrays:

```
    $mixed_carriers[0] = array(
     0 => "134",
     1 => "138",
     2 => "200",
    );

    $mixed_carriers[1] = array(
     0 => "272"
    );
```

I want combine them, and obtain this:

```
$mixed_carriers = array(
  0 => "134,272,",
  1 => "138,272,",
  2 => "200,272,"
);
```

What I need is merge two arrays, separating their values by comma.

Always take all the values of the largest array, and then concatenate the values of the other array...

could have 3 arrays...

Comment: Its cartesian of arrays.

Comment: This is not a sufficiently complex [mcve] if you may encounter more than 2 input arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cartesian product of array. You can use following snippet.

```
class Cartesian
{
    public static function build($set)
    {
        if (!$set) {
            return array(array());
        }
        $subset = array_shift($set);
        $cartesianSubset = self::build($set);
        $result = array();
        foreach ($subset as $value) {
            foreach ($cartesianSubset as $p) {
                array_unshift($p, $value);
                $result[] = $p;
            }
        }
        return $result;        
    }
}
$temp = Cartesian::build($mixed_carriers);
// implode by comma to every subarrays
$temp = array_map(function($item){ return implode(",", $item);}, $temp);
```

I used this class to get [cartesian](https://gist.github.com/jwage/11193216).

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/R94Yv).